# Column means 3d matrix (cube) Rcpp

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp, armadillo

I have a program in which I need to calculate repeatedly the column means of each slice of a cube `X(nRow, nCol, nSlice)` in Rcpp, with the resulting means forming a matrix `M(nCol, nSlice)`. The following code produced an error:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp; 
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

mat cubeMeans(arma::cube X){
   int nSlice = X.n_slices;
   int nCol = X.n_cols;
   int nRow = X.n_rows;
   arma::vec Vtmp(nCol);
   arma::mat Mtmp(nRow, nCol);
   arma::mat Means(nCol, nSlice);
   for (int i = 0; i < nSlice; i++){
      Mtmp = X.slice(i);
      for(int j = 0; j < nCol; j++){
         Vtmp(j) = sum(Mtmp.col(j))/nRow; 
      }
      Means.col(i) = Vtmp;
   }
  return(wrap(Means));
}
```

> '/Rcpp/internal/Exporter.h:31:31: error: no matching function for call to 'arma::Cube::Cube(SEXPREC*&)'

I couldn't quite figure it out. I didn't get the error when the input of the function was a matrix (and returned a vector). However, I included the above function as part of my main program i.e.

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

mat cubeMeans(arma::cube X){
  int nSlice = X.n_slices;
  ...
  return(Means);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]

main part of program
```

The program compiled successfully, but it is painfully slow (almost as slow as the R version of the program using `colMeans`). Is there a better way to calculate column means on a cube, and why am I getting that compilation error?

I'd appreciate any help.

Regards,

Comment: Almost as slow as colMeans??? ... then that is it. `colMeans` is optimized in C. Your lack of offering the code you used to run this program may contain the clue to answering the problem. BTW, there are no "3d matrices" in R. Arrays would be a different matter. Terminology is often important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also received this error when attempting to use an `arma::cube` as an Rcpp function parameter. <strike>Based on the compiler error, I believe this is because there is no `Rcpp::wrap<arma::cube>` currently defined (which is needed to handle the R object you would pass to the function).</strike>† After reading a couple of related examples online, it looks like the typical workaround is to read in your R `array` as a `NumericVector`, and since it retains its `dims` attribute, use these to set your `arma::cube` dimensions. Despite the fact that there is an extra step or two required to account for the <strike>missing `wrap` specialization</strike>†, the Armadillo version I put together seems to be quite a bit faster than my R solution:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat cube_means(Rcpp::NumericVector vx) {

  Rcpp::IntegerVector x_dims = vx.attr("dim");
  arma::cube x(vx.begin(), x_dims[0], x_dims[1], x_dims[2], false);

  arma::mat result(x.n_cols, x.n_slices);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x.n_slices; i++) {
    result.col(i) = arma::conv_to<arma::colvec>::from(arma::mean(x.slice(i)));  
  }

  return result;
}

/*** R

rcube_means <- function(x) t(apply(x, 2, colMeans))

xl <- array(1:10e4, c(100, 100 ,10))
all.equal(rcube_means(xl), cube_means(xl))
#[1] TRUE

R> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    "R Cube Means" = rcube_means(xl),
    "Arma Cube Means" = cube_means(xl),
    times = 200L)
Unit: microseconds
            expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
    R Cube Means 6856.691 8204.334 9843.7455 8886.408 9859.385 97857.999   200
 Arma Cube Means  325.499  380.540  643.7565  416.863  459.800  3068.367   200

*/
```

where I am taking advantage of the fact that the `arma::mean` function overload for `arma::mat`s will calculate column means by default (`arma::mean(x.slice(i), 1)` would give you the row means of that slice).

---

**Edit:** † On second thought, I'm not really sure if this has to do with `Rcpp::wrap` or not - but the issue seems to be related to a missing `Exporter<>` specialization for `arma::cube` - line 31 of Rcpp's Exporter.h:

```
template <typename T>
class Exporter{
public:
  Exporter( SEXP x ) : t(x){}
  inline T get(){ return t ; }

private:
  T t ;
} ;
```

Regardless, `NumericVector` / setting dimensions approach I used seems to be functional solution for now.

---

Based on the output dimensions you described in your question, I assumed you wanted each column of the resulting matrix to be a vector of column means of the corresponding array slice (column 1 = column means of slice 1, etc...), i.e.

```
R> x <- array(1:27, c(3, 3, 3))
R> rcube_means(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2   11   20
[2,]    5   14   23
[3,]    8   17   26
R> cube_means(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2   11   20
[2,]    5   14   23
[3,]    8   17   26
```

but it would be trivial for you to alter this if needed.