# Fast access to Rcpp::List elements

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a data set that I really want to work with as a 3D array.  Rather than deal with an attempt to get an R array into a RcppArmadillo Cube, which I'm not sure would work (?), I'm sending in a list of matrices.  My problem, however, is that the list is of large matrices and I want to be able to loop over the 3rd dimension in the middle of loops over rows or columns.  With medium size matrices (list of 20 matrices of size 50,000x5), flattening the list into one long array gets me my result in less than a second.

I'd prefer to avoid copying the data in order to accommodate larger matrices.  But using as< NumericMatrix >(list_obj[t]) inside a loop over the rows makes the function take several minutes at least.  An example of my code use as<> that is incredibly slow is below.  dat is the list sent into the function. steps is an int sent into the function.

```
T = dat.size()
N = as<NumericMatrix>(dat[0]).nrow()
M = as<NumericMatrix>(dat[0]).ncol()

// Temp vals                                                                  
double top, bot;

// Output vector                                                              
NumericVector out(M);

// Loop through each signal                                                   
for (int j=0; j<M; j++) {
    // Reset numerator and denominator                                          
    top = 0;
    bot = 0;

    // Loop through each time dimension                                         
    for (int tm = 0; tm < (T - steps); tm++) {

        // Loop through each row                                                  
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

            // Check if entry is positive                                           
            if (as<NumericMatrix>(dat[tm])(i, j) > 0) {
                // Increment denominator                                              
                bot += 1.0;
                // Compute future product                                             
                top = 1.0;
                for (int k = 1; k <= steps; k++) {
                    if (as<NumericMatrix>(dat[tm + k])(i, j) == 0) {
                        top = 0.0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        out(j) = top / bot;
    }
}
```

Is there a fast way to do this without flattening the matrix and requiring a full copy of the potentially large data?

Comment: FWIW you can work with (3D) R arrays as `arma::cube` objects; see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969799/column-means-3d-matrix-cube-rcpp/30981930#30981930).

Comment: Super helpful.  Didn't consider that the NumericVector Rcpp type would maintain it's 'dim' attribute if an R array were passed in, as a vector of numerics in R has a NULL 'dim'.

Comment: But vector != array.  If either of you wanted to contribute an `as<>()` for RcppArmadillo ...  We do take well written pull requests :)